# Looking to emulate the functionality of socat in Python

Tags: python, socketserver, socat

I need to send a string to a particular port on localhost using python.

I can achieve this by using socat on the command line like such:

```
cat <text file containing string to send> | socat stdin tcp-connect:127.0.0.1:55559
```

I don't want to run the socat command as a subcommand so I'd like to know how to get this working using a python module.

My attempts at using sockets failed. Below is a script I was using which wasn't achieving the desired effect.

```
    import socket
    HOST, PORT = "127.0.0.1", 55559
    jsonString = '{"name":"VideoStreamStatus","parameters":{"name":"video_0_0"}}'

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    try:
        # Connect to server and send data
        print "Attempting connection"
        sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
        print "Sending json string"
        sock.sendall(jsonString)
        print "String sent"

    finally:
        sock.close()

    print "Sent:     {}".format(jsonString)
```

The python script was executing without any errors but there wasn't any effect on the process which was receiving the socat data. Python script output below:

```
    Attempting connection
    Sending json string
    Sent:     {"name":"VideoStreamStatus","parameters":{"name":"video_0_0"}}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong in the socket script or is there a different method I can use in Python? I'd appreciate any advice. Thanks.

Edit: The server I'm trying to send strings to is part of a C++ program using boost asio acceptor to listen for tcp connections on a specific address and port.

Comment: Your code works perfectly well for me. My server, `nc -l 55559`, displays the json string on its stdout. Please describe the server you are using, and what makes you think that "*there wasn't any effect on the process which was receiving the socat data*".

Comment: @Robᵩ The server I'm trying to send strings to is part of a C++ program using boost asio acceptor to listen for tcp connections on a specific address and port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out to be something really simple. The string I was sending using socat (which the server was receiving and processing successfully) had a newline on the end of it. The string I was sending over the python socket didn't have a new line. After adding a new line to the end of the python script the server receives the string as expected.

I only realised that there was a newline after one and not the other after running a python server script listening on a different port and sending the string using both methods.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the socat man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/socat),

> When one channel has reached EOF, the write part of the other channel is shut down. Then, socat waits `timeout` seconds before terminating. Default is 0.5 seconds.

Perhaps you need to defer your close by 0.5 seconds, like so:

```
finally:
    #sock.close()
    sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    sock.close()
```

Or, perhaps you need to absorb the server's shutdown message, like so:

```
finally:
    #sock.close()
    sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    sock.recv(999999)
    sock.close()
```

Comment: Doesn't have any effect on the outcome. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You shall never close a socket immediately after writing into a socket: the close could swallow still unsent data.

The correct workflow is what is called a [graceful shutdown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738547%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

- the part that wants to close the connection uses a shutdown-write on the socket and keeps on reading
- the other part detects a 0 bytes read from the socket which is sees as an end of file. It closes its socket
- the initiator detects a 0 bytes read and can safely close the socket

So the `finally` part becomes:

```
finally:
  try:
    sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    while True:
        dummy = sock.recv(1024)
        if len(dummy) == 0: break
  finally:
    sock.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but making those changes hasn't changed the outcome, the server still doesn't seem to receive any messages.